# Maven dependency hell - previously removed repository appears during my build

Tags: maven, dependencies

Our project used to have a repository that now is deprecated [jboss - hibernate bug explained here](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/JBBUILD-682), we updated every single pom we had with the new repository, and it seemed to work just fine until today, when I decided to checkout the project and do a clean build into a new machine.

Now, I've got maven complaining that it can't reach the old repository. I've grepped the whole filesystem checking for the culprit and couldn't find it. But still I've got this

```
Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.jboss.aop:jboss-aop:jar:2.0.0-SNAPSHOT: Could not transfer artifact org.jboss.aop:jboss-aop:pom:2.0.0-SNAPSHOT from/to jboss (http://repository.jboss.com/maven2): Access denied to: http://repository.jboss.com/maven2/org/jboss/aop/jboss-aop/2.0.0-SNAPSHOT/jboss-aop-2.0.0-SNAPSHOT.pom -> [Help 1]
```

I have no idea what's going on, my theory (besides that this could be an x-file) is that other dependency somehow managed to include this repo? Am I right? How can I check this?

I tried to build the dependency tree (mvn dependency:tree) to see who is the one that tries to include it, but since the whole project can't build I can't get the dep:tree ~grin~

Can anybody explain me what exactly is wrong here? how can I debug it? "BTW -e option doesn't bring any other useful info, still I pasted it below for any eagle-eye expert out there :)"

So far, I've started to copy the whole ~/.m2/repository from other machine to the new one, hopefully this will make the trick. But still, I was expecting maven to download and build the project from scratch as it's supposed to do

Here is the stacktrace

```
Caused by: org.sonatype.aether.resolution.ArtifactDescriptorException: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.jboss.aop:jboss-aop:jar:2.0.0-SNAPSHOT
    at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.loadPom(DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.java:282)
    at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.readArtifactDescriptor(DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.java:172)
    at org.sonatype.aether.impl.internal.DefaultDependencyCollector.process(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:419)
    at org.sonatype.aether.impl.internal.DefaultDependencyCollector.process(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:533)
    at org.sonatype.aether.impl.internal.DefaultDependencyCollector.process(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:533)
    at org.sonatype.aether.impl.internal.DefaultDependencyCollector.process(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:533)
    at org.sonatype.aether.impl.internal.DefaultDependencyCollector.collectDependencies(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:243)
    ... 25 more
Caused by: org.sonatype.aether.resolution.ArtifactResolutionException: Could not transfer artifact org.jboss.aop:jboss-aop:pom:2.0.0-SNAPSHOT from/to jboss (http://repository.jboss.com/maven2): Access denied to: http://repository.jboss.com/maven2/org/jboss/aop/jboss-aop/2.0.0-SNAPSHOT/jboss-aop-2.0.0-SNAPSHOT.pom
        at org.sonatype.aether.impl.internal.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:541)
        at org.sonatype.aether.impl.internal.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifacts(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:220)
        at org.sonatype.aether.impl.internal.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifact(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:197)
        at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.loadPom(DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.java:267)
        ... 31 more
Caused by: org.sonatype.aether.transfer.ArtifactTransferException: Could not transfer artifact org.jboss.aop:jboss-aop:pom:2.0.0-SNAPSHOT from/to jboss (http://repository.jboss.com/maven2): Access denied to: http://repository.jboss.com/maven2/org/jboss/aop/jboss-aop/2.0.0-SNAPSHOT/jboss-aop-2.0.0-SNAPSHOT.pom
        at org.sonatype.aether.connector.wagon.WagonRepositoryConnector$4.wrap(WagonRepositoryConnector.java:949)
        at org.sonatype.aether.connector.wagon.WagonRepositoryConnector$4.wrap(WagonRepositoryConnector.java:940)
        at org.sonatype.aether.connector.wagon.WagonRepositoryConnector$GetTask.flush(WagonRepositoryConnector.java:695)
        at org.sonatype.aether.connector.wagon.WagonRepositoryConnector$GetTask.flush(WagonRepositoryConnector.java:689)
        at org.sonatype.aether.connector.wagon.WagonRepositoryConnector.get(WagonRepositoryConnector.java:445)
        at org.sonatype.aether.impl.internal.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:460)
        ... 34 more
Caused by: org.apache.maven.wagon.authorization.AuthorizationException: Access denied to: http://repository.jboss.com/maven2/org/jboss/aop/jboss-aop/2.0.0-SNAPSHOT/jboss-aop-2.0.0-SNAPSHOT.pom
        at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.LightweightHttpWagon.fillInputData(LightweightHttpWagon.java:119)
        at org.apache.maven.wagon.StreamWagon.getInputStream(StreamWagon.java:116)
        at org.apache.maven.wagon.StreamWagon.getIfNewer(StreamWagon.java:88)
        at org.apache.maven.wagon.StreamWagon.get(StreamWagon.java:61)
        at org.sonatype.aether.connector.wagon.WagonRepositoryConnector$GetTask.run(WagonRepositoryConnector.java:608)
        at org.sonatype.aether.util.concurrency.RunnableErrorForwarder$1.run(RunnableErrorForwarder.java:64)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)
```

Thanks in advance

**UPDATE 08/10/2011**

Seems that the problem is related to maven3. Last update from apple pushed some java changes including maven3. After download and set up maven2 and perform a full "mvn clean compile build" problem disappeared.

I'll update this thread when I've got more info on the issue

Thanks to everybody that answered and gave ideas. Your help is very much appreciated.

Comment: is the repository in your ~/.m2/settings.xml?

Comment: Grepped the whole file system? I'm thinking you missed something because this would be specified in one of your pom.xml files (top level is typical) or your settings.xml file under ~/.m2. Double check those?

Comment: @digitaljoel nope, not there, just server section filled in and with the credentials to one of my servers

Comment: @SingleShot well, not the whole FS, I gotta take that back, but indeed the whole project directory. _grep -nHr "repository.jboss.com" *_ returns **0**

Comment: I'm running into exactly the same problem. However, I can't switch back to Maven 2. Have you found another solution for it?

Comment: @Sebi Actually it runs with Maven 3 based on our jenkins, I'm not sure what exactly caused the issued. But after a full clean up at some point it just started working.

Comment: @maverick Yes, we also did some pom juggling and this problem went away. We still face many other problems, but at least this one is fixed. One key point to solve it was specifying the exclusion tag for the dependency importing the libs not being available.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of a dependency tree, use

```
mvn help:effective-pom
```

and search the output of that for the repo. If a multi-module build, make sure to run it at the top level to get all the poms at once. If it's not mentioned there, double check ~/.m2/settings.xml and $M2_HOME/conf/settings.xml for it. It's definitely somewhere in your file system. Maven doesn't just magically add repos.

Comment: Thx!, good approach, but unfortunately it didn't show that specific repo. only the one that we replaced it for _repository.jboss.org/nexus_

Comment: Did you check all of the `settings.xml`s?

Comment: yeap, the one at ~/.m2/ only has a server definition credentials, and the one at maven home installation, is the default with no "jboss.com" mentioned at all. Did I miss any other? I'll grep the whole disk tonight, has to be mentioned somewhere!

Answer (score 0):

If you use Eclipse, M2Eclipse's [Dependency Graph](http://www.sonatype.com/books/m2eclipse-book/reference/dependencies-sect-analyze-depend.html) is an alternative to dependency:tree which might work without requiring Maven to run against the POM.

When looking at dependency POMs for repos, you also need to look at parents/ancestors of those POMs.

Comment: thx good try but since the project doesn't compile eclipse shows it just blank

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you should relook at the specified dependency - `org.jboss.aop:jboss-aop:jar:2.0.0-SNAPSHOT`. It looks like [does not exist](https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/index.html#nexus-search;gav~org.jboss.aop~jboss-aop~~~~kw,versionexpand) in jboss repository.  You could try `2.0.0.GA` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You "updated every single pom ... with the new repository"?  Don't put repositories in your poms.

http://www.sonatype.com/people/2009/02/why-putting-repositories-in-your-poms-is-a-bad-idea/

I suspect Maven is trying to hit that repo because it is being referenced in the pom of a transitive dependency (Maven 3 uses *slightly* different dependency resolution than Maven 2), or else there may be something in the [compatibility notes](https://cwiki.apache.org/MAVEN/maven-3x-compatibility-notes.html) about repositories that is affecting you.